# Unable to match route in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code in my `app.js`:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/products', {
        templateUrl: '/angularjs/public/angular/views/product.html'
      }).
      otherwise({
        templateUrl: '/angularjs/public/angular/views/home.html'
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

When I go to home at `http://localhost/angularjs/public`, the `.otherwise` kicks in correctly.

If I go to `http://localhost/angularjs/public/products`, nothing happens, or more precisely, I believe `.otherwise` is invoked again, since is displayed the `home.html` view. Also no error is throwed in `batarang's` console.

What could be the problem?

Comment: This http://localhost/angularjs/public#/products will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add "public" to product slug in your route

```
when('public/products', {
    templateUrl: '/angularjs/public/angular/views/product.html'
  }).
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I had to do `/angularjs/public/products`, this part must be related to `xampp`.